# Django: custom template tag which takes 2 variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to have a custom template tag which takes two variables as arguments. This is what I have in my template:

```
{% load accountSum %}
{% accountSum 'account_id' 'account_type' %}
```

I have read that you need to load the context of these variables but I have not found a working way. So my question is, how do I define the custom template tag in templatetags/accountSum.py?

This is what I have so far:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def accountSum(context, account_id, account_type):
    account_id = context[account_id]
    account_type = context[account_type]
    # do something with the data
    # return the modified data

register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)(accountSum)
```

Comment: "some errors" - *what* errors?

Comment: The errors differ depending on the method I tried to use. The concept should be easy but I don't get it.

Comment: Sigh. Help us help you. Give us some examples of the methods you tried to use, and the errors you've got. What you have shown above would work fine, so there is absolutely no way to help you without more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the usage of template tags, `I have read that you need to load the context of these variables`... **context** is only required if you need to access/modify the existing context, not if you only need to return the calculated value from the provided arguments.

So, in your case, what you only need is this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def accountSum(account_id, account_type):
   # your calculation here...
   return # your return value here
```

**Django** document has a more detailed explanation and example that you can follow -- [Simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Or, if your intention is to take the **context** value **account_id** and **account_type** and return a modified value on each call, you can simply omit taking the **arguments**, and simply do this:

```
@register.simple_tag(take_context=True)
def accountSum(context):
    account_id = context['account_id']
    account_type = context['account_type']
    # do your calculation here...
    return # your modified value
```

Then you can simply call `{% accountSum %}` in your template.

Or, if you want to dynamically take context content as arguments:

```
@register.simple_tag(take_context=True)
def accountSum(context, arg1, arg2):
    arg1 = context[arg1]
    arg2 = context[arg2]
    # calculation here...
    return # modified value...
```

And passing arguments in template using **string** like:

`{% accountSum 'account_id' 'account_type' %}`

I hope this helps you understand how to use template tags in your case.

## updated

What I meant is this (as you don't need to access the context, what you really need is taking arguments just like usual):

```
@register.simple_tag
def accountSum(arg1, arg2):
   # your calculation here...
   return # your return value here
```

and use this in your template:

`{% accountSum account.account_id account.account_type %}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the last method but I get a "Key Error" for "account.account_id". I think the problem is that I am using it in a for loop like this:

`{% for account in bilanz_liste_passiv %}
    <tr>
     <td>
            {{ account.account_title }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% accountSum 'account.account_id' 'account.account_type' %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %} `

Comment: @kristian, if you're passing the **values** from account as arguments, simply go for the first approach without the need to access the context

Comment: @kristian, I've updated my answer for your use case. And you shouldn't **change** your question after trying my method, instead you should put an **update** or **edit** under your original question as an follow-up.

Comment: Thank you! The first approach worked perfectly. I had another problem in my code which I did not see.

Comment: @kristian, glad it helps ;) Just make sure you understand how `context` works in template. All the best.